# How to replace values in the rest of a column after certain threshold?

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume that I have a data frame below

```
Date <- as.Date("2020-01-01") + 0:9
Ticker <- rep("KO-US", 10)
Daily_Ret <- c(0.00803, 0, 0, 0.00469, -0.00468, -0.0193, -0.0120, -0.0141, 0, 0)
Cumulative_Ret <- c(1.19, 1.19, 1.19, 1.20, 1.19, 1.17, 1.15, 1.14, 1.14, 1.14) 
Daily_Cumulative_Ret <- tibble(Date, Ticker, Daily_Ret, Cumulative_Ret)

# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Date       Ticker Daily_Ret Cumulative_Ret
   <date>     <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 KO-US    0.00803           1.19
 2 2020-01-02 KO-US    0                 1.19
 3 2020-01-03 KO-US    0                 1.19
 4 2020-01-04 KO-US    0.00469           1.2 
 5 2020-01-05 KO-US   -0.00468           1.19
 6 2020-01-06 KO-US   -0.0193            1.17
 7 2020-01-07 KO-US   -0.012             1.15
 8 2020-01-08 KO-US   -0.0141            1.14
 9 2020-01-09 KO-US    0                 1.14
10 2020-01-10 KO-US    0                 1.14
```

I wanted to replace all values in the corresponding `Daily_Ret` column with 0, after the value 1.20 (or any threshold that I set) in the `Cumulative_Ret`. How do I do this (preferably using dplyr)? I know that I can use `filter(cumany(Cumulative_Ret >= 1.20))` to filter the values after, but not sure how to replace the corresponding values in `Daily_Ret` column with 0.

The end result would look something like this:

```
   Date       Ticker   Daily_Ret Cumulative_Ret
   <date>     <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 KO-US    0.00803           1.19
 2 2020-01-02 KO-US    0                 1.19
 3 2020-01-03 KO-US    0                 1.19
 4 2020-01-04 KO-US    0.00469           1.2 
 5 2020-01-05 KO-US    0                 1.19
 6 2020-01-06 KO-US    0                 1.17
 7 2020-01-07 KO-US    0                 1.15
 8 2020-01-08 KO-US    0                 1.14
 9 2020-01-09 KO-US    0                 1.14
10 2020-01-10 KO-US    0                 1.14
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the logical values returned by `cumany` in `replace` to change the values after 1.2 to 0. Possibly you also want to do this for each `Ticker`.

```
library(dplyr)

Daily_Cumulative_Ret %>%
  group_by(Ticker) %>%
  mutate(Daily_Ret = replace(Daily_Ret, 
                     lag(cumany(Cumulative_Ret >= 1.2), default = FALSE), 0))

#   Date       Ticker Daily_Ret Cumulative_Ret
#   <date>     <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1 2020-01-01 KO-US    0.00803           1.19
# 2 2020-01-02 KO-US    0                 1.19
# 3 2020-01-03 KO-US    0                 1.19
# 4 2020-01-04 KO-US    0.00469           1.2 
# 5 2020-01-05 KO-US    0                 1.19
# 6 2020-01-06 KO-US    0                 1.17
# 7 2020-01-07 KO-US    0                 1.15
# 8 2020-01-08 KO-US    0                 1.14
# 9 2020-01-09 KO-US    0                 1.14
#10 2020-01-10 KO-US    0                 1.14
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! If I would like to add another threshold for example < 0.95, I just add another line of mutate?

Comment: So you mean change all values to 0 after `Cumulative_Ret >= 1.2  Or Cumulative_Ret <= 0.95` ?

Comment: Yes, essentially what I would like to do is when ```Cumulative_Ret >= 1.2```, the rest of the values for ```Daily_Ret``` will be 0, or when ```Cumulative_Ret < 0.95```, the rest of values for ```Daily_Ret``` will be 0. I have many tickers in the same long data format.

Comment: I think changing the condition in `cumany` should do it. `cumany(Cumulative_Ret >= 1.2 |  Cumulative_Ret <= 0.95)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> Daily_Cumulative_Ret %>% group_by(Ticker) %>% 
+   mutate(rowid = which(Cumulative_Ret >=1.2)) %>% 
+     mutate(Daily_Ret = case_when(row_number() > rowid ~ 0, TRUE ~ Daily_Ret)) %>% select(-rowid)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Ticker [1]
   Date       Ticker Daily_Ret Cumulative_Ret
   <date>     <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 KO-US    0.00803           1.19
 2 2020-01-02 KO-US    0                 1.19
 3 2020-01-03 KO-US    0                 1.19
 4 2020-01-04 KO-US    0.00469           1.2 
 5 2020-01-05 KO-US    0                 1.19
 6 2020-01-06 KO-US    0                 1.17
 7 2020-01-07 KO-US    0                 1.15
 8 2020-01-08 KO-US    0                 1.14
 9 2020-01-09 KO-US    0                 1.14
10 2020-01-10 KO-US    0                 1.14
>
```